# OWASP-CSR on ATS

Tags: mod-security

I have some Apache Traffic Servers that use in CDN platform. Is it possible to configure OWASP-CSR on Apache Traffic Server? If yes, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way you can do this with Apache Traffic Server.

Comment: is this a comment or an Answer? i belive the first one.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer.

Comment: GJ, I upvote for beeing now an answer ;)